# Facing Error while install Firebase messaging pods

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

when Installing FirebaseMessaging pod its shows error.

> Analyzing dependencies
> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

This is my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Howl' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Howl
pod 'lottie-ios'
pod 'SKCountryPicker'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'CarbonKit'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'W3WSwiftApi'
pod 'what3words'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'Swift-EventBus'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
pod 'FacebookShare'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'Firebase'

  target 'HowlTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'HowlUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type anything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.